# Passing variables between view controllers in swift

Tags: ios, variables, swift

I have a problem with changing passed variable between two view controllers.

In the first view controller I do next:

```
var index: NSNumber = 0

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if segue.identifier == "secondView" {
    let dest = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
    dest.index = index
  }
}
```

In the second next:

```
var index: NSNumber!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  index = 1
  self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

But the variable "index" has not been changed after interaction. What is wrong?

Please help me, I spent on that problem whole night!

Comment: What is intended to happen?  You're passing the data correctly, but in the second view's viewDidLoad you're overwriting it with 1.

Comment: It must be overwritten in the first view through the second view

Comment: Oh the you're going to need to pass data back from the second view or use a global variable

Comment: I understand that, but I cannot understand the next one: why i can change the attributes of passed objects, but cannot overwrite whole object by another object?

Comment: Well when you pass data through the segue, you copy a value into a variable in the second controller.  You don't actually pass the object, you pass the data it contains. When you change the attributes in the second controller, it changes for only that controller because the variable is on that controller. The variable on the first controller is unaffected because you just copied its data, not the actual reference to the variable.

Comment: Nope, bro. I have debugged and seen on watcher that the address of the passed object on the second controller equal to the first object. But when i overwrite the address changes.

Comment: both index variables will hold the same NSNumber object before viewDidLoad is called. But when it reaches the index = 1 statement in viewDidLoad the object held by index is replaced with another object (here it's 1). The index is firstviewcontroller will still have the old object. The 2 indexes are two different variables(they have two different memory locations)

Comment: Problem solved. The solve was in managedcontext. I have changed the attributes of the NSManagedObject, and all changes holds in context. Thankee